# rails geocoder alexreisner automatically add the users locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rails-geocoder

Hi i am currently working on alexreisner geocoder and i need to adjust it so that the users dont have too add their address , latitude and longitude in the forms but when they submit their form it will be automatically filled and they dont have to add their address latitude and longitude

is it possible to automatically do this?will it be safe or secure? and how to do this?

this is the database that i currently have and working with

```
create_table "quests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer in the [documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder):

You just have to add this in your model

```
geocoded_by :address              # can also be an IP address
after_validation :geocode         # auto-fetch coordinates
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you using the rails app for a webapp, than you need to get the coordinates from the users browser. You can do this with javascript.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPositionByBrowserCoordinates) if navigator.geolocation
```

Inside the callback (here `setPositionByBrowserCoordinates`) you can set for example hidden fields with the gotten coordinates. They will be send to your server on submit and than you can save them.

It's all working automatically for the user. The only thing that the user needs to do, is to permit you access to the position.

Mozilla Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition